# Embed only the "Contact us" fields and not the rest of the information

Tags: magento-1.9

Our "contact us" page has a chunk of text above the input fields which tells customers about our working hours, contact number etc.

I want to embed the "contact us" fields in another template but without the text above.

Can I just copy the fields and submit button from:

 `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\contacts\form.phtml`
and put them in my template, or is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to copy that file in your current theme `app/design/frontend/{theme}/{name}/template/contacts/form.phtml`and you customize it as your need.

I mean by customize add some divs, classes, remove/update labels, titles etc...

If you want to add some extra fields, you can but, you have also to create new attribute, and rewrite the contacts module controller to get your extra fields.

**Update:**

To embed it in cms page:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contact.form" form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: But can I copy the content of `form.phtml` and paste it in another template, modify it (leave the fields as is) and use it in another CMS page for example?

Comment: Look my update,  copy it in your current theme like mentioned above, update it then you can get it in your cms page like my update, if you want to leave the base (form.phtml) as it is currently and you want to create another one just for the cms pages for exemple, you can copy it with another name form-cms.phtml, update it then change the name template in `{{block type... ttemplate="contacts/form-cms.phtml"}}`

Comment: Great, answers my question:)